Switching automatically the quality
I am new in using ffmpeg and mp4box. I have been encoding one mp4 file to create different qualities using ffmpeg then I'll generate an mpeg dash using mp4box. The mpd file that is generated is being played at better_player from flutter. It is working well and I can play the mpd. However, I cant seem to find the auto quality in qualities section of the player. Here is the image attached.
This is my command in ffmpeg:
'-preset slow',
'-g 48', 
'-keyint_min 48',
'-sc_threshold 0',
'-profile:v main',
'-crf 20',
'-bufsize 1200k',
`-vf scale=-2:${quality.height}`

This is my command in mp4box:
`MP4Box -dash 4000 -rap -profile dashavc264:live -bs-switching multi -url-template -out ${outputPath} ${mediaFiles.map(file => `${file.video}#video`).join(' ')} ${mediaFiles[0].audio}#audio`;

